# Tunisia's list of designated terrorist organizations?

Tags: terrorism, tunisia

[According to BBC:](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-23853241)

> Tunisia has designated the hardline Salafist Ansar al-Sharia movement a "terrorist group"
>
> [...] "Anyone belonging to it must face judicial consequences," he added.

Does Tunisia have an "official list of designated terrorist organizations", like [India](http://www.mha.gov.in/uniquepage.asp?Id_Pk=292), [Australia](http://www.nationalsecurity.gov.au/agd/WWW/NationalSecurity.nsf/Page/What_Governments_are_doingListing_of_Terrorism_Organisations) and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations)?

If yes, where can it be seen? (preferably online)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such an "official list", at least for the moment, since Ansar al-Sharia is the first organisation to be considered as such.

Comment: Reference? Is there any official document (written by the Tunisian government) that says Ansar al-Sharia is now designated?

Comment: Apart from the fact the prime minister announced that in a press conference, something I wouldn't call "reference", there is no document that I am aware of. 

Not to mention that the Tunisian Gvmt is far from being transparent. That document may exist but not published.